# gets() statement in loop asks for input only once

Tags: c++, loops, gets

In part of my code, there is a `gets()` statement inside a loop that is supposed to ask for input every time it iterates. However, it only asks for input once and doesn't ask again when the loop runs again, as though some input has already been made. This is really annoying as there doesn't seem to be anything wrong.

```
while(5) {
    cout<<"Is your number "<<x<<" ?\n[yes/no]\n";
    gets(ans);
    if (strcmpi(ans,"yes")==0)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Do note that `gets` has been removed from C++14 and beyond.  You should switch over to `getline` if you are working with strings or just use `>>`

Comment: @sleekmaster292  How is gets that even is not supported by the C Standard connected with C++?

Comment: [mcve] please. Also, don't use `strcmpi`. `==` works just fine for strings

Comment: @AndyG except OP is probably not using std::string.

Comment: @Borgleader: Good point. I'd like to retro-fit my comment to suggest using `std::string`, too

Comment: @AndyG Agreed, `char*` -> `std::string`, `gets` -> `std::getline` (or `>>` depending), and `strcmpi` -> `==`.

Comment: @AndyG `==` does a case sensitive comparison.  `strcmpi` does case **in**sensitive.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: `gets` was part of the standard library in the original C++, and still present in C++11.  `fgets` is still part of standard C++.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Thanks for pointing that out. `strcmpi` is deprecated, however. OP should use `boost::iequals`, or transform `ans` to lowercase before the comparison instead.

Comment: @MartinBonner gets is deprecated since C++14 though.

Comment: Are you trying to write portable code or platform-specific code? If platform-specific, what platform? If portable, why are you assuming `\n` is an appropriate line ending?

Answer (score 0):

`get()` is not inside C++[14] and higher versions. You now use `getline()` instead. `std::cin` works effective too but depends on what you are doing or your personal preference.